# How to add one array of ComboBoxItem to multiple ComboBox in wpf programmatically?

Tags: wpf, combobox

I'm trying to add arrays of ComboBoxItem to multiple ComboBox,
but after selecting one ComboBox, others where affect selection.

My Codes:

```
Dim arrColors() As ComboBoxItem = {
            New ComboBoxItem With {.Content = "سفارشی", .HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, .VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top},
            New ComboBoxItem With {.Content = "آبی", .Background = TryFindResource("BrushPrimary"), .HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, .VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top},
            New ComboBoxItem With {.Content = "سبز", .Background = TryFindResource("BrushSuccess"), .HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, .VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top},
            New ComboBoxItem With {.Content = "زرد", .Background = TryFindResource("BrushWarning"), .HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, .VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top},
            New ComboBoxItem With {.Content = "قرمز", .Background = TryFindResource("BrushDanger"), .HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, .VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top},
            New ComboBoxItem With {.Content = "سفید", .Background = TryFindResource("BrushLight"), .HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, .VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top},
            New ComboBoxItem With {.Content = "مشکی", .Background = TryFindResource("BrushDark"), .HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, .VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top},
            New ComboBoxItem With {.Content = "طوسی", .Background = TryFindResource("FormBackground"), .HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, .VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top},
            New ComboBoxItem With {.Content = "خاکستری", .Background = TryFindResource("SplitterColor"), .HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, .VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top},
            New ComboBoxItem With {.Content = "صورتی", .Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Pink), .HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, .VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top},
            New ComboBoxItem With {.Content = "بنفش", .Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple), .HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, .VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top},
            New ComboBoxItem With {.Content = "قهوه‌ای", .Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown), .HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, .VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top},
            New ComboBoxItem With {.Content = "نارنجی", .Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange), .HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, .VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top},
            New ComboBoxItem With {.Content = "آبی کمرنگ", .Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue), .HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, .VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top},
            New ComboBoxItem With {.Content = "سبز کمرنگ", .Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen), .HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, .VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top}
}
```

Tryed methods:

```
cmbThemeBack1.ItemsSource = New List(arrColors.Clone)
cmbTextColor1.ItemsSource = arrColors.Clone
```

But none of that was right.

Comment: Try using `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`.

Comment: Thanks trix, but It still doesn't work. `cmbThemeColor1.ItemsSource = New ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of ComboBoxItem)(arrColors)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each instance of `UIElement` is only allowed to exist once in the XAML object graph. This means you can't create a `UIElement` e.g., a `ComboBoxItem` and then add it as child to multiple elements e.g., a `ComboBox`.

### Option 1

Create each `ComboBox` with individual `ComboBoxItem` instances:

```
<StackPanel>
  <StackPanel.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushWarning" Color="Orange" />
  </StackPanel.Resources>
  
  <ComboBox  x:Name="FirstComboBox">
     <ComboBox.Items> 
       <ComboBoxItem Content="First Item" Background="{StaticResource BrushWarning}" /> 
       <ComboBoxItem Content="Second Item" /> 
     </ComboBox.Items> 
  </ComboBox>

  <ComboBox  x:Name="SecondComboBox">
     <ComboBox.Items> 
       <ComboBoxItem Content="First Item" Background="{StaticResource BrushWarning}" /> 
       <ComboBoxItem Content="Second Item" /> 
     </ComboBox.Items> 
  </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

I recommend using XAML over C# as some operations are much more convenient e.g. resource lookup using the `StaticResource` markup.

### Option 2 (recommended)

Use a shared source collection of data models and let the framework create the `ComboBoxItem` elements dynamically by using a `DataTemplate`:

**ItemModel.cs**
For improved performance it is recommended to *always* let the binding source implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (even if you won't raise the `PropertyChanged` event at all).

```
Public Class ItemModel
    Inherits INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(Brushes.Transparent)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal background As Brush)
        Me.Background = background
    End Sub

    Public Property Background As Brush
    Public Property Text As String
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName> ByVal Optional propertyName As String = Nothing)
        Me.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
End Class
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**
For best performance implement the binding source as a `DependencyProperty`.

```
Partial Class MainWindow
    Inherits Window

    Public Shared ReadOnly ItemModelsProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ItemModels", 
    GetType(ObservableCollection(Of ItemModel)), 
    GetType(MainWindow), 
    New PropertyMetadata(Nothing))

    Public Property ItemModels As ObservableCollection(Of ItemModel)
        Get
            Return CType(GetValue(MainWindow.ItemModelsProperty), ObservableCollection(Of ItemModel))
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of ItemModel))
            Return SetValue(MainWindow.ItemModelsProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        Me.ItemModels = New ObservableCollection(Of ItemModel) From {
            New ItemModel With {
                .Text = "First Item",
                .Background = Brushes.Yellow
            },
            New ItemModel With {
                .Text = "Second Item",
                .Background = Brushes.Blue
            }
        }
    End Sub
End Class
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Name="Window">
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Background}" />
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ItemModel}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
 
  <StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="FirstComboBox"  
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=ItemModels}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemTemplate}" />
    
    <ComboBox x:Name="SecondComboBox" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=ItemModels}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemTemplate}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Note that if you wouldn't have to color each row individually, you could just create a collection of `string` and bind it to each `ComboBox`. This way you wouldn't need to define a `DataTemplate`, because `ComboBox` (or `ItemsControl` in general) would automatically create a `TextBlock` to display each `string`.

Comment: Thanks BionicCode! Apparently, it is not possible to copy ComboBox items in wpf!

Comment: You can copy ComboBoxItem. In OO programming to copy an object instance means to create a new instance of this object and then copy every attribute values or references of the source instance to the new instance, usually by using a copy constructor or a factory method like Clone(). You can implement a helper method to create shallow copies of ComboBoxItem. But since adding item containers like ComboBoxItem directly to an ItemsControl is not recommended I didn't showed this option. The easiest is to use data models like in option 2. This way you don't have to create duplicate collections.

Comment: Copying every ComboBoxItem still means duplicate collections - one for each ComboBox.